# How to Edit a form in React by using functional components

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In my project I have a form, In that form I fetch data by Id

From the backend, Now I am trying to do put method. But I have no idea how doing it so please me

How to send edited data to backend using the put method.

This is my code Editstudentdetails.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Editstudentdetails.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

function Editstudentdetails(props) {
    const [getStudentDataById, setStudentDataById] = useState([])

    const [editStudentDataById, latestEdit] = useState({ name:'', position: '', location: '', salary: '', email: '', password: '' })

    const id = props.match.params.id
    console.log(id)



    useEffect(() => {
        const getDataById = async () => {
            try {
                const result = await axios.get(`http://localhost:7500/api/registration/${id}`)
                setStudentDataById(result.data)
                console.log(result.data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
        getDataById()
    }, [])


    const handleChange = ({ target }) => {
        const { name, value } = target

        const newData = Object.assign({}, getStudentDataById, { [name]: value });
        setStudentDataById(newData);

        const latestData = Object.assign({}, editStudentDataById, { [name]: value })
        latestEdit(latestData)
    }

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.warn(editStudentDataById)
        const editDataById = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.put(`http://http://localhost:7500/api/registration/${id}`, editStudentDataById)
                latestEdit(response.data)
                console.warn(response.data)
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn(error)
            }
        }
        editDataById()
    }
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" name='name' value={getStudentDataById.name} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="name"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="position">Position</label>
                            <input type="text" name='position' value={getStudentDataById.position} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="position"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="location">Location</label>
                            <input type="text" name='location' value={getStudentDataById.location} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="location"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="salary">Salary</label>
                            <input type="number" name='salary' value={getStudentDataById.salary} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="salary"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                            <input type="email" name='email' onChange={handleChange} value={getStudentDataById.email} className="form-control" id="email"></input>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name='password' onChange={handleChange} value={getStudentDataById.password} className="form-control" id="password"></input>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}


export default withRouter(Editstudentdetails)
```

If you feel I am not clear with my doubt please put a comment Thank you

Comment: What errors do you get currently?

Comment: Hi @AdamJeliński I am not getting any errors, I am trying to console by this way         console.warn(editStudentDataById). So If I get  all the  updated data like what I edited and what not edited then I can send that data to backend.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work pretty well. Does your ```console.warn(editStudentDataById)``` give the output you are expecting?

Comment: If edit only name, then the value is changing in console, but remaining all are coming empty because I made state empty please go through my code once again.

Comment: Is your problem only related to sending the data? If so, I would try changing ```await axios.put(`http://http://localhost:7500/api/registration/${id}`, editStudentDataById)``` to ```await axios.put(`http://http://localhost:7500/api/registration/${id}`, JSON.stringify(editStudentDataById))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow this example. It works perfectly.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function EditStudentDetails() {
    const [post, setPost] = useState({});
    const id = 1;

    const handleChange = ({target}) => {
        const {name, value} = target;
        setPost({...post, [name]: value});
        console.log(post);
    };

    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const editDataById = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.put(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
                    method: 'PUT',
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        id: id,
                        title: post.title,
                        body: post.body,
                        userId: 1
                    }),
                    headers: {
                        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(json => console.log(json));
                console.warn(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
        };
        editDataById();
    };
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='row'>
                <div className='col-4'>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="name">Title</label>
                            <input type="text" name='title' value={post.title} onChange={handleChange}
                                   className="form-control" id="title"/>
                        </div>
                        <div className="form-group">
                            <label htmlFor="position">Body</label>
                            <input type="text" name='body' value={post.body}
                                   onChange={handleChange} className="form-control" id="body"/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EditStudentDetails;
```